# how to cut the last 3 fields from line and print total tokens numbers

Tags: linux, awk, perl

How to cut the last three fields from the following cli

```
cat file.txt
```

The output

```
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 0    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1001,1003        Isr: 1002,1003,1001
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 1    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1002,1001        Isr: 1002,1003,1001
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 2    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1003,1002        Isr: 1002,1003,1001
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 3    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1003,1001        Isr: 1002,1003,1001
```

Expected output

```
1002 1003 1001
1002 1003 1001
1002 1003 1001
1002 1003 1001

Number of tokens are : 12
```

We try the following but without success

```
cat file.txt |awk '{print $NF-3,$NF-2,$NF-1}'
```

Comment: The value of the `NF-3` column is `$(NF-3)`, not `$NF-3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use both comma and space characters as field separators:

```
awk -F "[, ]" '{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}' file
```

To write the final tokens statement too:

```
awk -F "[, ]" '{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF;i++}END{print "Number of tokens are: " i*3}' file
```

Comment: is it possible to print only the Number of tokens are , without all numbers?

Comment: @yael Yes, you just remove the first print statement, assuming each line has three tokens, but know your data. Even `awk 'END{print NR*3}' file` would do it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have two different separations (space- and comma-separated - I will disregard the `:`), you will have to be rather careful with how you choose the *field separator*.

The default is (one or more) spaces, so your statement `$(NF-3),$(NF-2),$(NF-1)` etc. should actually print

```
Replicas: 1002,1001,1003   Isr:
```

which are the fourth-to-last to the next-to-last space-separated tokens on your line.

For your task, you would choose the last space-separated token, and split that in addition at the comma, as in

```
awk '{n=split($NF,tokens,","); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%s%s",tokens[i],i==n?ORS:OFS)}' file.txt
```

This takes the last field `$NF`, `split`s it at the `,`, and stores the resulting "sub-fields" to an array `tokens`. It returns the number of such sub-fields and stores it as `n`. Then, we print all these sub-fields with separator character being either the "output field separator" (`OFS`, defaults to space) when we are *not* at the end of the `tokens` array, or the "output record separator" (`ORS`, defaultso to newline) when we have reached the last token.

That way, you are also flexible against variations of the number of tokens in that last field.

**In order to print a grand total**, the line would be modified as:

```
awk 'NF{n=split($NF,tokens,","); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%s%s",tokens[i],i==n?ORS:OFS); tot+=n}\
     END{printf("Number of tokens: %d\n",tot)}' file.txt
```

The `NF` condition preceding the first rule ensures that empty lines are ignored (they would confuse the counting logic).

**In order to *only* print the grand total**, you can omit the `printf` statements:

```
awk 'NF{tot+=split($NF,tokens,",")} END{printf("Number of tokens: %d\n",tot)}' file.txt
```